# Using module import in android studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, actionbarsherlock

I'm having a problem using the actionbarsherlock module, in my android studio project. I was successful in making it as a library in the project, but I can't import from it. 
"import com.actionbarsherlock..." just dosent work. my Settings.gradle looks like this:

```
include ':app',  ':actionbarsherlock'
```

The actionbarsherlock module is in the same folder as is "App", ".idea" and "build". 
May the location be the problem, or is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `include` statement in your *settings.gradle* simply includes that project as a subproject in your Gradle build. You will then need to include that project as a dependency in your *build.gradle*.

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':actionbarsherlock')
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) this was the problem